# Replace fragment from another activity. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to navigate to a fragment from an activity.
Two fragments FragmentA and FragmentB are used in a navigation drawer.
Please find code below:

FragmentA.java

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment{

Button btnContinue;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragA, container, false);
    btnRegister=(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_register);
    btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Intent i =new Intent(getActivity(),Register.class);
        startActivity(i);

       }
     });

    return rootView;
  }
}
```

Register.java is another activity in which i have a save details button click.

```
btnSave.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        new Save_register_detail_task(Register.this,newfirstname, newlastname, newemail, newpassword).execute();

       }
     });
```

Save_register_detail_task.java (AsyncTask). 
In its onPostExecute i have following code:
**R.id.frame_container is defined in Navigation Drawer's layout.**

```
Fragment fragment = new FragmentB();
            fragment.setArguments(bundle);  
            //activity.finish();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((FragmentActivity)activity).getSupportFragmentManager();

            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
                    .beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_container,
                    fragment, "fragb")
                    .addToBackStack("register")
                    .commit();
```

**LogCat-**

```
09-08 13:24:21.381: E/FragmentManager(32202): No view found for id 0x7f050143     (com.demo.projectdemo:id/frame_container) for fragment FragmentB{429831a8 #0 id=0x7f050143 fragb}
09-08 13:24:21.381: E/FragmentManager(32202): Activity state:
09-08 13:24:21.431: E/AndroidRuntime(32202): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-08 13:24:21.431: E/AndroidRuntime(32202): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view   found for id 0x7f050143 (com.demo.projectdemo:id/frame_container) for fragment  FragmentB{429831a8 #0 id=0x7f050143 fragb}
09-08 13:24:21.431: E/AndroidRuntime(32202):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:930)
09-08 13:24:21.431: E/AndroidRuntime(32202):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1115)
09-08 13:24:21.431: E/AndroidRuntime(32202):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
09-08 13:24:21.431: E/AndroidRuntime(32202):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1478)
09-08 13:24:21.431: E/AndroidRuntime(32202):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:446)
09-08 13:24:21.431: E/AndroidRuntime(32202):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
09-08 13:24:21.431: E/AndroidRuntime(32202):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-08 13:24:21.431: E/AndroidRuntime(32202):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-08 13:24:21.431: E/AndroidRuntime(32202):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4960)
09-08 13:24:21.431: E/AndroidRuntime(32202):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-08 13:24:21.431: E/AndroidRuntime(32202):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-08 13:24:21.431: E/AndroidRuntime(32202):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
```

**What should I use in place of R.id.frame_container?? or is there any other way for declaring Fragment Manager??**

Comment: does your next view has `setContentView(R.layout.yourlayot)` in `onCreate()`

Comment: in place of R.id.frame_container you can use any VievGroup id you have in FragmentB view hierarchy

Comment: FragmentB has View rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.shipping, container, false);

Comment: @pskink that does not solve my problem..using any ViewGroup id from FragmentB will throw same error.

Comment: @AndroidGeek how can you access other's Activity ftom another Activity? this design is wrong

Comment: @AndroidGeek : Why are you using Fragments in a Navigation Drawer? Do they do something complex?

Comment: @Squonk didn't you notice that > 50% folsk here use fragments everywhere for everything without any reason?

Comment: @pskink : Yep, that hasn't escaped my attention. Personally I haven't needed to find a use for Fragments in a Navigation Drawer but I suppose it could be done.

Comment: @pskink:  Can you please suggest me how to do this stuff other way round?

Comment: @Squonk: How can we implement navigation drawer without using fragments?

Comment: call startActivityForResult and catch the result in calling Activity

Comment: @Squonk: I am referring:-(http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html)

Comment: @AndroidGeek they have a list view in the left drawer and a frame layout as a content,  where do they say either of them must be a fragment?